# emails get delivered to SPAM

Tags: sendgrid

I have been using this [SDK](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) for email delivery within my application.

I tried to send an email to my private email address in hotmail, but got delivered to SPAM.

```
<?php
// If you are using Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "myhotmail@hotmail.com");
$subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "noreply@mydomain.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "some text here");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

However if I changed the sender address to "mygmail@gmail.com" it could get delivered to Inbox. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that gmail is much more aggressive at putting things in the spam folder.  SendGrid has setup stuff that includes DKIM records.  I'd suggest confirming you have that setup correctly.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/dkim.html

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to Microsoft enforcing a stricter [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/) policy than Gmail. Your originating IP address is not allowed to send email on behalf of hotmail.com because the hotmail.com SPF and DKIM records don't include it. This causes a DMARC failure, meaning strict policies will drop or junk the email. The trend among email receivers is implementing strict DMARC policies in order to fight phishing. Generally speaking it's not a viable long-term strategy to send email from a domain you don't control.